# My category toggle is not expanding correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to expand the child item from the category, it is not working perfectly check the output here https://codepen.io/limon213/pen/GbXaxd

If there is a gap with not containing the child item, it is not skipping the correct item

```
<ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#/">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Parent 2</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Parent 3</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i><a href="#">Parent 4</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i><a href="#">Parent 5</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i><a href="#">Parent 6</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Parent 7</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Parent 8</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i><a href="#">Parent 9</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Parent 10</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-parent"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i><a href="#">Parent 11</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the javascript code is

```
$('.product-categories li').on('click',function() {
            let i = $(this).index();
            $('.children').eq(i).toggle();
            $( ".cat-parent .icon" ).eq(i).toggleClass( "fa-minus" );
        });
```

I think this is generating for the index, It is not skipping the correct item.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery selectors are applied across the whole document by default. You can constrain them to the descendants of a particular element by using the second, optional argument as [described in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Here's what it should look like:

```
$('.cat-parent').on('click', function() {
  $('.icon', this).toggleClass('fa-minus');
  $('.children', this).toggle();
}
```

But, really, I'd move most of the style changes into CSS so that the javascript only has to change a single class:

```js
$('.cat-parent').on('click',function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.cat-item > .children {
  display: none;
}
.cat-item.open > .children {
  display: block;
}
.cat-item.open > .fa-plus:before {
  content: "\f068";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Actually, I am not an expert in JavaScript. I am trying to learn :) but it is too complex for me :( trying to watch lots of tutorials.